# Is it possible to use a Guid with Oracle's Entity Framework Core Package?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core

We have been using Devart's entity framework core implementation but are experiencing extremely poor performance. We originally went with Devart because Oracle had not made anything yet. They have finally implemented something but it is choking on GUIDs. When querying a table that contains a Guid column (stored as raw(16) in the database I receive a "Method Not Supported" error. Upon further investigation it appears Oracle's did not implement the GetGuid method expected by EF core. Is there a way around this with mappings or anything?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I don't think it is possible, currently. On a side note I was able to solve my Devart performance issues by removing using statements on my context. It seems like Devart disposes of too much when disposing the context.